# What is the state-of-the-art method/algorithm to extract Keywords from text?

Tags: data-mining, text-mining

What is the state-of-the-art method/algorithm to extract data from text without regarding the language of the text?

The methods I am reading about are Rake, Yake or using LTSM Networks to identify Keywords.

Are there any ressources on what Amazon, Google or Facebook use for this?

Can anybody here share his experience regarding Keyword extraction?